# xmarks and iPhone Safari

Tags: synchronization, bookmarks, xmarks

Is it possible to sync my iPhone Safari's bookmarks with my [xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xmarks have now released an official iPhone App!

http://itunes.apple.com/app/xmarks-for-iphone/id381187793

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by syncing xmarks to IE or Safari a PC or Mac, then syncing that with the iPhone via iTunes.

A one step solution would be better though!